# How to properly sort a List of object and clone it

Tags: list, flutter, dart

so i was creating this app which is an item catalogue for an online shop using StaggeredGridView, here i add a function to sort the item from a list, so that i can sort it by price or make it back to default sorting, but i encounter a problem where the list cant go back to default sorting when i select it, here is the code :

```
class ItemCatalogState extends State<ItemCatalog>{

  sortedBy sorted = sortedBy.init;
  bool isInit = true;
  var selectedList = [];

  void sortItem(List<Item> initialList){
    switch (sorted) {
      case sortedBy.lowestPrice:
        setState(() {
          selectedList.sort((a,b){return a.price.compareTo(b.price);}); 
        });
        break;
      case sortedBy.highestPrice:
        setState(() {
          selectedList.sort((a,b){return b.price.compareTo(a.price);});
        });
        break;
      case sortedBy.init:
      //NOT WORKING
        setState(() {
          selectedList = initialList; 
        });
        break;
       default:
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    List<Item> itemList = Provider.of<List<Item>>(context);
    
    if(isInit&&itemList!=null){
      selectedList = itemList.map((e) => Item(image: e.image,name: e.name,isReady: e.isReady,price: e.price,seller: e.seller)).toList();
      isInit = false;
    }

    sortItem(itemList);

    return Container(
          child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
            child: DropdownButton(
              value: sorted,
              items: [
                DropdownMenuItem(
                  child: Text('Default',),
                  value: sortedBy.init,),
                DropdownMenuItem(
                  child: Text('Lowest',),
                  value: sortedBy.lowestPrice,),
                DropdownMenuItem(
                  child: Text('Highest'),
                  value: sortedBy.highestPrice,),
              ], 
              onChanged: (value){
                setState(() {
                  sorted = value;
                });
              }),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: kGrayMainColor,
                  ),
                  child: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
                    itemCount: selectedList!=null?selectedList.length:itemList.length,
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      Item currentItem = selectedList!=null?selectedList[index]:itemList[index];
                      return ItemTile(item: currentItem, size: size,);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
      ]),]
    );
  }
```

It was supposed to call the original List when i click the default drop down, but nothing changed, could i possibly wrong at copying the list to selectedList? Thankyou and any advice regarding my other bad code practice is appreciated since im still learning.

Comment: What is the default sorting? Alphabetically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `sortItems` you set `selectedList` to be equal to `initialList`. From that point on, both variables are now pointing at the same collection of objects, which means anything you do to one, you will also do to the other. And since you are getting the collection through provider, these changes will also affect the original list that was provided.

Instead of a direct assignment, copy `initialList` again so that the two lists are never pointing to the same collection.

Incidentally, there's a much easier way to create copies of lists:

```dart
selectedList = List.from(initialList);
```

On another note, I'm assuming that the default value of `sorted` is `sortedBy.init`. That makes the initial copy within your `build` method redundant as the `sortItems` method immediately overwrites the value of `selectedList`. Instead, just depend on `sortItems` to generate your list without having to worry about initialization:

```dart
void sortItem(List<Item> initialList){
  switch (sorted) {
    case sortedBy.lowestPrice:
      selectedList = List.from(initialList)
        ..sort((a,b) => a.price.compareTo(b.price));
      break;
    case sortedBy.highestPrice:
      selectedList = List.from(initialList)
        ..sort((a,b) => b.price.compareTo(a.price));
      break;
    case sortedBy.init:
      selectedList = List.from(initialList); 
      break;
  }
  setState(() {}); // Just call this once to reduce code duplication and verbosity
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ...

  List<Item> itemList = Provider.of<List<Item>>(context);
  sortItems(itemList);

  ...
}
```

Comment: Thankyou.. this works for me, i forgot that selectedList changed in the first sortItem called, also thanks for the code tips

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would solve it (I changed your `List<Item>` to a `List<String>` for simplicity, but you get the gist):

Load the original list into the _sortedList variable (initially in didChangeDependencies) via the Provider and repeat this whenever you are in need of the original list again.

(My Provider returns `['aa', 'dd', 'cc']`, so I could get in that map() you do on the list as well :) )

```
enum SortOrder { ascending, descending, original }

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  var _sortedList = List<String>();

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    _loadOriginalList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Ascending'),
                onPressed: () => setState(() => _sortList(SortOrder.ascending)),
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Descending'),
                onPressed: () => setState(() => _sortList(SortOrder.descending)),
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Original'),
                onPressed: () => setState(() => _sortList(SortOrder.original)),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: _sortedList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => Center(
              child: Text(_sortedList[index]),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _sortList(SortOrder sortOrder) {
    switch (sortOrder) {
      case SortOrder.ascending:
        _sortedList.sort();
        break;
      case SortOrder.descending:
        _sortedList.sort();
        _sortedList = _sortedList.reversed.toList();
        break;
      case SortOrder.original:
        _loadOriginalList();
        break;
    }
  }

  void _loadOriginalList() {
    final originalList = Provider.of<List<String>>(context, listen: false);
    _sortedList.clear();
    _sortedList.addAll(originalList.map((e) => e.substring(0, 1)));
  }
}
```